# Can I export animations from separate objects into one take, without using a rig?

Tags: animation, export, actions

So I had this problem for a while and worked around it, but I need this to work now in Blender.

Below you can see a simple animation I made in Maya. The two objects are animated separately and move at the same time.
[image]

Below here you can see the same animation in Blender.
[image]

Now if I export these two animations to an fbx (In maya using the "game exporter" and in blender using the normal fbx export), the maya export will have both animations on a single take and blender will have them on their own respective takes plus sharing each others takes too, making it 4 animations instead of 2.

[image]
[image]

Is there a way I can export these animations, as separate objects with separate animations, onto one take like the maya game exporter?

Comment: In the fbx exporter window in Blender at the left-below corner, click on the "Animation" tab and disable "All Actions" and "NLA Strips".

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was broken because I tried disabling "all actions" but then the animations were gone. I see now you have to have both disabled for it to work. Thanks @FFeller